# Rally: Creating tables dynamically

Tags: rally

I'm building a report in Rally that finds all the defects which have been reopened,  Then it looks to see if they have been reopened more than once.  The table will list ID, description, creation date, then reopened dates.  The problem is when I'm building the config file I have no idea how many reopened dates I'm going to need.  I see ways of building the table itself dynamically but I cant figure out how to create the config file dynamically in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this too. You have to find all your information before you build the table.

You need :

```
-global array
-configuration object (mine is global but it doesn't have to be)

    configSettings = [
    {key: 'something1', header: 'something2', etc}
    {key: ...
    ]
```

You need as many

```
{key: 'something1', header: 'something2', etc}'s
```

as columns in your table. For example, if you have `"schedulestate"` and `"blocked"`, then you will need two of those.

Now, each time you loop looking for stuff, you create an object that has the same form as an item in the configuration settings.

```
localvar = {'something1' : "whatever you want to set it to", 'something2': 'set this to something'};
```

You can make something1 and something2 rally objects, like dropdowns or checkboxes or whatever. You can put hyperlinks in there, too.

After you have created localvar, you must push it onto the global array:

```
globalArray.push(localvar);
```

When you have finished looping, you can create the table.
Like Kyle said, it's hard to answer this without a code snippet from you.